# Xbox Music Cloud collection not available on Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, xbox-music

Very simple, and I assume the only issue is that Xbox Music isn't bug free yet.  All of my music that has been cloud matched are on both my XPS 10 tablet (Windows RT) and on my Windows 8 laptop.  But when go to Music, Songs, filter by Cloud Collection on my Lumia 920 Windows Phone 8, I only see the three sample files that came with the phone (Fatima, Sixteen and Wonderland).

I have tried turning "Xbox Music cloud collection" on and off on my phone.  But no luck.  Any tricks on getting my music on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Xbox Music is a cloud-based music service, so you don't physically connect to a PC to sync music. If you have an Xbox Music Pass, which requires a monthly fee, then you can stream or download music on your phone. If you don't have a pass, you can still buy music from the Xbox Music Store.

If you use Windows 8 and have an Xbox Music Pass, you can manage your music in the Windows 8 Music app, and changes there will automatically sync to your phone as a cloud collection. Cloud collection songs appear on your phone in the Music + Videos Hub, but there are no actual song files on your phone. You can tell a song is in your cloud collection by the cloud streaming icon Cloud streaming icon that appears next to it.

For example, if you create a playlist using songs from the Xbox Music catalog on your Windows 8 PC, the playlist and the songs in it will then appear on your phone in the Music + Videos Hub. If you make changes to the playlist in the Windows 8 Music app, the playlist on your phone will automatically change, too.

Cloud collection songs can be streamed over a cellular or Wi-Fi connection, or you can download them as files to your phone—just tap and hold a song, and then tap Download (or tap the Select Select button button to choose several songs at once).

Of course, you don't necessarily have to use the cloud collection on your phone. If you want to see only the music files that you have stored on your phone, you can go to Settings Settings icon, flick to Applications, tap Music + Videos, and then turn off Xbox Music cloud collection.
Notes

- You can use Xbox Music on a limited number of devices at the same
  time. If you've reached the limit, you can always remove a device to
  make room for a new one.
- If you have an active Zune Pass subscription associated with the same
  Microsoft account that you use for Windows Phone 8, then you will
  automatically have an Xbox Music Pass subscription on your phone.
- Xbox Music Pass and the cloud collection work only with Windows 8 and
  Windows Phone 8. Windows Phone 7 users should continue to use the
  Zune software to manage their media.

  - To save battery life and reduce data usage, the phone checks for new
    cloud content periodically. If you want to check for new content
    immediately, tap the Start Start button button, and then tap Music +
    Videos Music+Videos icon to refresh the Music + Videos Hub.

Answer (score 1):

Had a Twitter discussion with @windowsphonesupport and @thurott and both told me that you have to pay for Cloud Synching on Windows Phone.  I guess Microsoft has every right to charge for any service they want, but it seems a bit illogical that you can cloud play or free on Windows 8, but it costs a fee on Windows Phone.  The only difference in the cellular bandwidth, which I pay for anyway.  The music is mine, so now instead of getting from the cloud, I have to copy manually to the phone.

Oh well, that's just the way it is.  Xbox Music costs too much for what you get for it, so I will pass and continue to use Nokia Music+.

Comment: Cloud play is not totally free on the desktop - there is an allowance of how much you play per month free of charge, but after that, you need an Xbox Music Pass, which would also get those tracks to your phone